# USB hub problems on the Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I got a USB hub on my Xbox 360 Slim, so that I could have more space.  How come neither of my flashdrives showed up on the any of the storage devices?

Comment: Do these devices show up if they are directly plugged into the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2):

Many devices don't work with USB hubs because it does not provide them enough power. Connect your device directly to the ports on Xbox Slim and not the USB hub and they should work.